# Laravel api route post calls work as expected, get call return blank html response

Tags: laravel, api

My laravel app has multiple route handlers including web, api, admin, and a new one that's misbehaving: "advisor".

The web, api, and admin routes all work as expected.

**For the advisor routes POST requests work as expected, but GET calls return the client-app.blade.php html file.  Not authorized or 404, just that html file.**

I have the advisor routes added in the map function just like the web and api routes are:

```
protected function mapAdvisorRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('advisor')
         ->middleware('advisor')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/advisor.php'));
}
```

The auth guards are setup as follows (AWS Cognito authentication is working properly on POST):

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],


'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'advisor' => [
        'driver' => 'cognito',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],


'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
    ]

],...
```

The issue is that the advisor GET calls are not executing the controllers or even middleware.  advisor POST calls are authenticating and working as expected.  Here are some example advisor routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function () {

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:advisor'], function () {

    Route::get('get-test', function () {
        // ISSUE: is not returned
        return 'advisors get test';
    });

    Route::post('post-test', function () {
        return 'advisors post test - works as expected';
    });


});});
```

My client-side app is sending the auth and accept headers - Authorization: Bearer {token} and Accept: "application/json"

**Any idea what would cause the response to an api call to be the client-app.blade.php file?**
**Or why would laravel treat the POST vs GET calls differently?**

**Thanks!**

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

As is often the case, writing out the problem helped me realize what was causing the problem.

The order of route mapping in RouteServiceProvider.php matters.

Changing this:

```
$this->mapApiRoutes();
$this->mapWebRoutes();
$this->mapAdvisorRoutes();
```

to this solved the problem:

```
$this->mapApiRoutes();
$this->mapAdvisorRoutes();
$this->mapWebRoutes();
```

The following line in web.php was causing the index or client-app.blade.php file to be returned.

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'ClientAppController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

So my /advisor GET request was never getting to the advisor route logic.

Phew!